# the code from puppeteer docs wont work bc of UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: javascript, npm, puppeteer

so i tried the example code on the puppeteer docs https://pptr.dev/ and it wont work.
i have puppeteer 3.0.0 installed via npm.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://example.com');
  await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});

  await browser.close();
})();
```

it fires: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)

so i tried this code:

```
'use strict';

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  try {

    await page.goto('https://example.com');
    await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});

} catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
} finally {
    await browser.close();
  }

})();
```

Edit: full error

```
(node:12856) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Failed to launch chrome!


TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md

    at onClose (C:\Users\tim\Desktop\te\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\Launcher.js:348:14)
    at ChildProcess.helper.addEventListener (C:\Users\tim\Desktop\te\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\Launcher.js:338:60)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:194:15)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12)
(node:12856) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:12856) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a
non-zero exit code.PS C:\Users\tim\Desktop\te>
```

but it still fires the same error. What did i do wrong?

Comment: Can you share the stack trace of the UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning?

Comment: @hardkoded is that what you need? see edit pls

Comment: Did you follow the troubleshooting posted on the error?

Comment: @hardkoded yes. It did not help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error already said that it fail to launch chrome.
So I guess it is something wrong with your chrome

You might want to try some of the suggestions posted here 
https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/807